# How can I (efficiently) reference nuget library and update it's source?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, workflow, metrics

I am depending on an open-source library via NuGet and need to fix the code. How can i *efficently* do that? (without changing all references or and fiddling with version numbers).

I have the following specific scenario in Visual Studio 2015 for .NET:

1. My Application contains multiple solutions that use "Metrics.NET", referenced in via NuGet packages
2. There is an issue in Metrics.NET (ActionScheduler causes cascading Task-creation when having many Timers which ends up consuming all threads).

I have tried:

1. Searching the web and reading the NuGet documentation :)
2. Including the library as source in my solution => Runtime errors of with missing (conflicting) references unless I change the reference in *every* single project in the solution
3. Generating a NuGet library from the Metrics.Net Sources => Hacking around in the versions of Metrics.NET for each change iteration (to make it update) and slow update-cycles, a local nuget-path and a solution wide update to the new (locally compiled) pre-release package (which almost certainly will collide with other packages on version-numbering). This approach also requires (temporarily) checking in the compiled package or setting up a NuGet distribution point and coordinating with other developers.

There *must* be a simpler workflow! What is it?

Comment: I dont find that abvious. While NuGet may not, by itself, have such workflow support maybe some poor other dev has already made a powershell-script or vs20xx extension that makes this workflow much less painfull.

Comment: The source is readily available, and includes project for creating a NuGet package, but the workflow to *utilize* such a package locally is very painful. Is the intent unclear?

I am not able to comprehend why C# being a compiled language has anything to do with this. I also fail to understand how a case for packages without source makes it obvious that there should be no support for such workflows.

Comment: @LexLi, NuGet can deliver source code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841855/packing-source-code-with-nuget

Answer (score 0):

You can try [NuGet Reference Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2017).
Note however, that it has a big number of [opened issues](https://github.com/RSuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher), so it may not work exactly as you want.

See also related question [How to see source code from github in Visual Studio IDE, but compile with dlls from Nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560156/how-to-see-source-code-from-github-in-visual-studio-ide-but-compile-with-dlls-f?rq=1)